# How to avoid duplicate entry in vb 2012 I am using .\sqlexpress database

Tags: vb.net

Hello can somebody help me how to avoid duplicate entry in vb 2012 may database is sqlexpress and i use dataset and tabaleadapter to instert data into the database please help me avoid the duplicate

Comment: It may take a while to wade thru all those details to determine the problem.

Comment: You've put no thought into this at all.  Do that, make an attempt and then get back to us with a specific issue if one occurs.  It should be obvious to anyone, even with zero programming knowledge, the type of approach to take.  If you had a cupboard full of cans of soup and you wanted to make sure that you had no more than one of each variety, what would you do? Would you maybe look in the cupboard to see if the one you were about to add was already there? Wouldn't that be common sense? We will be happy to help when you hit an actual problem.